# React anime api search

Tags: reactjs

Hey guys i have a small problem. I am building react anime api. I want to be able to search an anime and get results.But i am stucked.I have searchbar in Header and i have search component seperately.It is a simple problem but i couldn't figure it out myself here is my code.Can someone edit my code so that i can understand.

Header.js

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function Header() {
    
  
  return (
   
      <div className='header'>
        <form action='/search'>
            <input type='text'  placeholder='search an anime'></input>
        </form>
        <form action='/random' method='get'>
            <input type='submit'  value="random anime"></input>
        </form>
        <form action='/upcoming'  method='get'>
            <input type='submit' value="upcoming animes" ></input>
        </form>
        <form action='/' method='get'>
            <input type='submit' value="popular animes"></input>
        </form>
        <form action='/character' method='get'>
            <input type='submit' value="popular characters"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
   
  )
}

export default Header
```

Search.js

````
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Search() {
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSearch = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q='+searchData, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setSearchData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchSearch();
  }, [searchData]); 

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='animes'>
        {searchData && searchData.data && searchData.data.length > 0 ? (
          searchData.data.map(anime => (
            <a className="anime-card" href={`/anime/${anime.mal_id}`} key={anime.mal_id}>
              <img src={anime.images.jpg.image_url} alt="Anime Image" />
              <p>{anime.title}</p>
            </a>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No data available</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;```



I tried putting useeffect and usestate in search.js into header but couldn't get it to work.When i write inside usestate naruto like this useState("naruto") i get all naruto animes so code works but i just don't know how to handle different components.
````